# Someone could explain what is happening with the code?

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

I want to guess what type of letter the user types down.

```
var userLetter = prompt("Enter a letter and I will tell you what type of letter is","Enter here, wish me luck!");

function selectUserLetter(letter) {
    var returnType = "NA";

    if (userLetter.charCodeAt(0) >= "A".charCodeAt(0) && userLetter.charCodeAt(0) <= "Z".charcodeAt(0)) {
        returnType = "U";
    }
    else if (userLetter.charCodeAt(0) >= "a".charCodeAt(0) && userLetter.charCodeAt(0) <= "z".charcodeAt(0)) {
        returnType = "L";
    }
    else if (userLetter.charCodeAt(0) >= "0".charCodeAt(0) && userLetter.charCodeAt(0) <= "9".charcodeAt(0)) {
        returnType = "N";
    }

    return returnType;
}

switch (selectUserLetter(userLetter)) {
    case "U": 
        document.write("Your letter is Uppercase");
        break;

    case "L":
        document.write("Your letter is Lowercase");
        break;

    case "N":
        document.write("Your letter is a number");
        break;

    default:
        document.write("You typed anything else");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code, fragments `"Z".charcodeAt`, `"z".charcodeAt(0)` and `"9".charcodeAt(0)` consist of `charcodeAt` function call. The thing is that JavaScript is case sesitive langauge. So, `charcodeAt` doesn't exists rather then `charCodeAt`.

Comment: so silly my mistake... I thought i had some problem with the variables or the parameter. Thank you so much!